# ASP.NET MVC api Assigning a list to a class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a class definition like so:

```
[XmlRoot("Developments")]
public class DevelopmentsClass : List<Development> { }
```

and in my controller I have this function:

```
public DevelopmentsClass getFeed()
{

  DevelopmentsClass returnDevelopments = new DevelopmentsClass();
  List<Development> developments = new List<Development>();

  Development development = new Development();

  //A bunch of code assigning variables to development and then adding development to developments
  return returnDevelopments;

}
```

My question is, how do I assign developments to DevelopmentsClass? I had to make this change to have XmlRoot and I don't want to rewrite a bunch of code....Is there a quick way to assign developments to DevelopmentsClass?

Comment: I am banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out

Comment: There has to be away to assign developments to DevelopmentsClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
returnDevelopments.AddRange(developments);
```